# Simulate a mouse release Pyqt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, signals, pyside

How can i simulate mouse release action using Qt.SIGNAL?
I need to simulate a mouseRelease without user's interaction. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example using the [`clicked`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) signal of a [`QPushButton`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qpushbutton.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.pushButtonSimulate = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButtonSimulate.setText("Simulate Mouse Release!")
        self.pushButtonSimulate.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonSimulate_clicked)

        self.layoutHorizontal = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layoutHorizontal.addWidget(self.pushButtonSimulate)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButtonSimulate_clicked(self):
        mouseReleaseEvent = QtGui.QMouseEvent(
            QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease,
            self.cursor().pos(),
            QtCore.Qt.LeftButton,
            QtCore.Qt.LeftButton,
            QtCore.Qt.NoModifier,
        )

        QtCore.QCoreApplication.postEvent(self, mouseReleaseEvent)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            print "Mouse Release"

        super(MyWindow, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Just what i was looking for! Excelent answer!

Comment: I tried exactly same code but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.
      press = QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseButtonPress, pos, Qt.LeftButton, 
      Qt.LeftButton, Qt.NoModifier)
      print("Testing2")
      release = QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseButtonRelease, pos, 
      Qt.LeftButton, Qt.LeftButton, Qt.NoModifier)
      print("Testing3")
      QApplication.postEvent(self.view, press)
      time.sleep(1)
      QApplication.postEvent(self.view, release)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
from PyQt4.QtTest import QTest

#(...) Where you want to release
QTest.mouseRelease(widget_to_release, Qt.LeftButton)
```

This will release the mouse at the center of the widget.

There are also methods for `mousePress()`, `mouseClick()`, and others. However, if you're testing Drag & Drop on Windows, be careful that the equivalent `QTest.mousePress()` will block, since `QDrag.exec_()` blocks.